# I can't start my Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, nvidia, intel, startup-applications, selinux

[image]

I can't start my computer anymore (nothing changed). It shows the Ubuntu logo with the five white dots becoming orange and white again, endlessly. No error, no login screen.

Comment: You might need to provide more information. Were updates applied? What did you do before the last restart? The message you provide looks like there was a bad shutdown, as if you lost power or pulled the power cord...

Answer (score 0):

Your filesystem was not cleanly unmounted. Probably the computer was powered off suddenly or you have problems in the hard drive.
You can boot your system with a rescue disk or a Ubuntu Live and fsck the drive to find errors.

In order to recover is important to know if you had the drive encrypted or not, and if you have empty space. Some times you may just fix the problem by making a bit of free space if you ran out of.

If the problem was in the boot you could use:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair